# Calculate the average of other averages in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table where I want to calculate the average response time from all users based on the `cat_id` and from a `join` based on the `user_id`'s country which are stored in another table.

What is the proper way to find the average time based on the user's country?

```
+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| user_id | cat_id | time1 | time2 | time3 | time4 | time5 | time6 | time7 |
+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|      11 |      1 | 10000 |  3500 | 10000 | 10000 |  7000 |  6000 |  6500 |
|       0 |      1 |  6139 |  2640 |  5438 |  8136 |  7157 |  8723 |  4677 |
|      11 |      3 |  7500 |  5500 | 10000 |  5500 |  7500 |  4000 |  9500 |
|       0 |      3 |  7462 |  8907 |  7513 |  4181 |  7275 |  2074 |  4444 |
|       1 |      1 |  8500 |  2000 |  8500 |  1500 | 10000 |  6500 | 10000 |
|       0 |      1 |  8885 |  7240 |  2153 |  6115 |  6330 |  6151 |  4325 |
|       1 |      1 | 10000 |  3000 | 10000 |  5500 | 10000 |  9000 | 10000 |
|       0 |      1 |  6188 |  3280 |  4725 |  5662 |  3344 |  8792 |  7560 |
|       1 |      4 |  4000 |  4500 | 10000 |  5000 |  3000 |  1500 |  2112 |
|       0 |      4 |  2750 |  4861 |  3413 |  4174 |  3080 |  3213 |  7932 |
+---------+--------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I've tried: `(AVG(time1 + time 2 + ... + time7) / 7)` but when I cross-check the results are not correct.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: 1. Normalise your schema. Any time you find yourself within enumerated columns, alarm bells should start ringing. That aside, there are no countries here, so the problem is insoluble.

Comment: @Strawberry unfortunately I can't change anything in the database. Also, this is from the ``users`` table where I can perform a ``Join`` and get the ``country``

    +----+---------+
    | id | country |
    +----+---------+
    |  0 | TEEEST  |
    |  1 | TEEEST  |
    |  2 | TEEEST  |
    |  3 | TEEEST  |
     +----+---------+

Comment: In which case create a view as follows: `SELECT user_id, cat_id, 1 time_no, time1 time FROM my_table UNION ALL SELECT user_id, cat_id,2, time2 FROM my_table...etc.` And then use that view for the next part of the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is taking an average of averages. I would first calculate the sum and count for each row and left join to add the country. Once you have your tabular data, you can summarize and do averages across country, cat, or both. Something like this:

```
select country, cat_id, (sum(total_time)/sum(count)) as avg_response_time
from (
select a.user_id
      ,a.cat_id
      ,b.country
      ,(a.time1 + a.time2 + a.time3 + a.time4 + a.time5 + a.time6 + a.time7) as total_time
      ,7 as count
from a
left outer join b
on a.user_id = b.user_id
)
group by country, cat_id
```

Comment: MySQL doesnt support WITH ... as ()

Comment: @RaymondNijland I did not know that. Thanks! I've updated accordingly.

Comment: @JeremyReal this worked like a charm, but MysQL insisted that you need an ``AS somename GROUP BY country...``. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all there's a problem with your parenthesis, which should be

```
AVG((time1 + time2 + ... + time7) / 7)
```

Then you may need to add something in your group by clause, depending on the level you want the average to be calculated at.

Answer (score 0):

You  should in first calculate average for row `(time1 + time2 + ... time7)/7`
and then calculate average for all rows `AVG((time1 + time2 + ... time7)/7)`